# How can I search for a specific line of text in all the files on my Mac?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word

I'm looking for a specific word (“attorney”) in *all* of my files on my Mac. I know this word exists in at least one Notes file, but when I search in the finder, nothing comes up. How do I do a more comprehensive search?

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
Eve's-MacBook-Air:~ evefairbanks$ sudo find / -iname "attorney*" -print
```

Comment: Why not just do a Spotlight search for “attorney?” That’s the whole idea of [Spotlight](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204014): “With Spotlight, you can find apps, documents, and other files on your Mac.” And if you are specific about the Notes app just launch it and do a search within the content of Notes.

Comment: That command doesn't work because sudo find looks for filenames. So you're searching / root for all files with attorney* in their name.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that command does not work because you're searching file names.

Try this:

```
sudo grep -rnw '/' -e 'attorney*'
```

Comment: Decent answer. This might technically work, but if you read the question it seems like this is all a content issue that can be solved by either using Spotlight or doing  a search within the Notes application itself.